# Error is setting Cacehs Configuration for Oracle Coherence

Tags: java, oracle-coherence

I am having following exception while trying to running oracle coherence project.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at my.core.server.JSWServerDelegate.main(ServerDelegate.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.uiDesigner.snapShooter.SnapShooter.main(SnapShooter.java:59)
Caused by: (Wrapped) java.io.IOException: Could not load cache configuration resource file://etrading-cache-config.xml
    at com.tangosol.util.Base.ensureRuntimeException(Base.java:296)
    at com.tangosol.util.Base.ensureRuntimeException(Base.java:277)
    at com.tangosol.net.ScopedCacheFactoryBuilder.loadConfigFromURI(ScopedCacheFactoryBuilder.java:399)
    at com.tangosol.net.ScopedCacheFactoryBuilder.buildFactory(ScopedCacheFactoryBuilder.java:428)
    at com.tangosol.net.ScopedCacheFactoryBuilder.getFactoryInternal(ScopedCacheFactoryBuilder.java:272)
    at com.tangosol.net.ScopedCacheFactoryBuilder.getFactory(ScopedCacheFactoryBuilder.java:235)
    at com.tangosol.net.ScopedCacheFactoryBuilder.getConfigurableCacheFactory(ScopedCacheFactoryBuilder.java:115)
    at com.tangosol.net.CacheFactory.getConfigurableCacheFactory(CacheFactory.java:154)
    at com.tangosol.net.CacheFactory.getConfigurableCacheFactory(CacheFactory.java:136)
    at com.tangosol.net.DefaultCacheServer.getConfigurableCacheFactory(DefaultCacheServer.java:702)
    at com.tangosol.net.DefaultCacheServer.main(DefaultCacheServer.java:416)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not load cache configuration resource file://my-cache-config.xml
    at com.tangosol.net.ScopedCacheFactoryBuilder.loadConfigFromURI(ScopedCacheFactoryBuilder.java:396)
```

I have already explored [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24290_01/coh.371/e22837/gs_config.htm#COHDG5009) from oracle which mentioned that as long as your property file is in class path it should run, but it is not running. I am setting up the property file using system property.

The other thing I noticed that code run fine and load property in eclipse but it does not run in intellij.

Answer (score 0):

my apology, it appear that the final place where that property file was being referenced has space in it, so although the name of property file was correct but due to space coherence was not able to find the file. I am posting this answer on how I resolve that error.